# Powershell The last logon user in the remote computer

Tags: powershell

I want a script that collects all logons from the organization's computers, and shows the last user logon and the most user's access in the computer.

I run this script from domain controller, but i only get the computer and the last logon, I don't have the last user logon or the frequency of logon.

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties * | FT Name, LastLogonDate, user -Autosize
```

Comment: You don't get logged-on user from `Get-ADComputer`. You need to parse the computer's security log, or log something with logon script to gather this info.

Comment: [Related](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/lastlogon.shtml).

Comment: do you know the code to take this?

Comment: you can use `Get-EventLog Security -InstanceId 528`

Comment: @RanadipDutta The event ID changed with Windows Vista it's 4624 now.

Comment: Oo . fine fine. thanks for letting me know@ansgar. Its been longtime I have used that. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can search the security event logs on a machine to get its last login.

```
$startDate = (Get-Date) - (New-TimeSpan -Day 5)
$UserLoginTypes = 2,7
Get-WinEvent  -FilterHashtable @{Logname='Security';ID=4624;StartTime=$startDate}  | SELECT TimeCreated, @{N='Username'; E={$_.Properties[5].Value}}, @{N='LogonType'; E={$_.Properties[8].Value}} | WHERE {$UserLoginTypes -contains $_.LogonType}  | Sort-Object TimeCreated | SElect -last 1
```

That will search the last 7 days for interactive logins or unlocks on the computer and return the most recent one.

Update to get most logged in:

```
$startDate = (Get-Date) - (New-TimeSpan -Day 7)
$UserLoginTypes = 2,7
Get-WinEvent  -FilterHashtable @{Logname='Security';ID=4624;StartTime=$startDate}  | SELECT TimeCreated, @{N='Username'; E={$_.Properties[5].Value}}, @{N='LogonType'; E={$_.Properties[8].Value}} | WHERE {$UserLoginTypes -contains $_.LogonType}  | group UserName |  Sort-Object Count | Select -last 1
```

Comment: really thanks, this code is good for me but i need one last thing:
I need to know who is the user who makes multiple logon from a computer.
For example, in an Active directory scenario in a single computer, so much users can logon in a computer, but i need to know who is The most used user.
please help me!!!!!

Comment: you can pick the `$_.userid` /sid of the user

Comment: If you want a count you can just add a group by.  updated post